# Connect to Enterprise WiFi on Windows issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt, wlanapi

I configured the Radius Server on Windows Server 2016 and I want to connect to Enterprise WiFi network using my application. I tried to do the following steps:

Set the profile without credentials using **WlanSetProfile** (I used imported profile from netsh with some modifications)

Then set the xml profile below with my username and password to **WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <EapHostUserCredentials xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostUserCredentials" 
   xmlns:eapCommon="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon" 
   xmlns:baseEap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapMethodUserCredentials">
   <EapMethod>
     <eapCommon:Type>26</eapCommon:Type> 
     <eapCommon:AuthorId>0</eapCommon:AuthorId> 
   </EapMethod>
   <Credentials xmlns:eapUser="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapUserPropertiesV1" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:baseEap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapUserPropertiesV1" 
     xmlns:MsPeap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapUserPropertiesV1" 
     xmlns:MsChapV2="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2UserPropertiesV1">
     <baseEap:Eap>
       <baseEap:Type>26</baseEap:Type> 
       <MsChapV2:EapType>
         <MsChapV2:Username>test</MsChapV2:Username> 
         <MsChapV2:Password>test</MsChapV2:Password> 
       </MsChapV2:EapType>
     </baseEap:Eap>
   </Credentials>
 </EapHostUserCredentials>
```

Then I use **WlanConnect** function and callback function to verify the connection. When connecting I get the following issue:

NotificationCode returns code 8 (wlan_notification_acm_scan_fail) and then 11 (wlan_notification_acm_connection_attempt_fail).

Also, from MS docs:

**wlan_notification_acm_scan_fail:**

> A scan for connectable networks failed.
>
> The pData member of the WLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA structure points to a
>   WLAN_REASON_CODE data type value that identifies the reason the WLAN
>   operation failed.

So, I checked the pData when this issue occurs and it returns the following reason:

*wlan_notification_acm_scan_fail
"The operation was successful."*

But the network is not connected. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. The problem was because the PerformServerValidation was set to true and it displayed the notification dialog to verify the certificate on Windows that's why it returned:

> wlan_notification_acm_scan_fail "The operation was successful."

Setting the PerformServerValidation  to false fixed the issue (WlanSetProfile function).

```
<PerformServerValidation xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2\">false</PerformServerValidation>
```

Also, for WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData function I provided this profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<EapHostUserCredentials
xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostUserCredentials"
xmlns:eapCommon="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon"
xmlns:baseEap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapMethodUserCredentials">
<EapMethod>
<eapCommon:Type>25</eapCommon:Type>
<eapCommon:AuthorId>0</eapCommon:AuthorId>
</EapMethod>
<Credentials
xmlns:eapUser="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapUserPropertiesV1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:baseEap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapUserPropertiesV1"
xmlns:MsPeap="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapUserPropertiesV1"
xmlns:MsChapV2="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2UserPropertiesV1">
<baseEap:Eap>
<baseEap:Type>25</baseEap:Type>
<MsPeap:EapType>
<baseEap:Eap>
<baseEap:Type>26</baseEap:Type>
<MsChapV2:EapType>
<MsChapV2:Username>username</MsChapV2:Username>
<MsChapV2:Password>password</MsChapV2:Password>
</MsChapV2:EapType>
</baseEap:Eap>
</MsPeap:EapType>
</baseEap:Eap>
</Credentials>
</EapHostUserCredentials>
```

Now it connects successfully to Enterprise network. The issue is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While calling WlanSetProfile(), make sure you are setting WlanProfileFlags as AllUser.